# Flask 404 Catch requested url

Tags: flask

I'm catching 404 errors on my website with this function:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    logger.warning('User raised an 404: {error}'.format(error=str(e)))
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

But I would like to know which url the user tried to access to raise the 404, is they a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `request.path` to know which url tried to access and raised 404.

Comment: It's better to use `request.url` in order to get the full URL.

Comment: yes.. I'm always using `"{}/{}".format(request.script_root, request.path)` to show correct path to user, this will be `'/accounts/login.html'` or something... And I don't want to show the host path.

Comment: Agree, that also makes sense