# How to get to URL of a HttpException in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to log flask exceptions with the following code

```py
    rotate_file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('flask-error.log', maxBytes=1024 * 1024 * 10, backupCount=10)
    rotate_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s][%(name)s]:\t%(message)s")
    rotate_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.logger.addHandler(rotate_file_handler)
    .........
    .......
    .......
    @app.errorhandler( werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException)
    def handle_exception(e):
        """Return JSON instead of HTML for HTTP errors."""
        # start with the correct headers and status code from the error
        response = e.get_response()
        # replace the body with JSON

        _data = json.dumps({
            "code": e.code,
            "name": e.name,
            "description": e.description,
        }).encode().decode('utf-8')
        try:
            raise ResourceWarning(_data) from e
        except Exception as e2:
            dumpError(e2, app=app)

        # response.data = _data
        # response.content_type = "application/json"
        return response
```

However some exception messages always occur and flood the log file:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 975, in send_static_file
    return send_from_directory(self.static_folder, filename,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 709, in send_from_directory
    raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

I know it is trying to tell me some html or resource lost, but I can't get its URL from the Exception log.

Does anyone know how to fetch the url of an HttpException?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer here [flask-404-catch-requested-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346512/flask-404-catch-requested-url)

```py
from flask import Flask, request
....
....
....
    @app.errorhandler( werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException)
    def handle_exception(e):
        exception_url = request.url
        print(exception_url)
        ......
        .......
        return response
```

And the output would be:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/plugins/socket.io.min.js.map